# model performance of multiple classes F1 score, recall .. etc

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, confusion-matrix

the Performances (showed down "screenshot") is given for each class and i want the performance for the whole model.
what should i do .... sum the columns and Divide it on class number or there is another way.
[image: click here to show performance for each class]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance on the whole model is already available to you, in the form of `macro avg` and `weighted avg`.

You can actually infer that from the support (11004).

For more information with regard to `macro avg` and `weighted avg`, you can check the following link: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65839/macro-average-and-weighted-average-meaning-in-classification-report